# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\main\sign_up.php on line 17

Tags: php

Here is my error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\main\sign_up.php on line 17

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('page_edit.php');
    if(isset($_POST ['signup'])){
        $fullname = $_POST['fname'];
        $username = $_POST['uname'];
        $email = $_POST['em'];
        $country= $_POST['con'];
        $password = $_POST['pw'];
        $gender= $_POST['gender'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `bookstore`.`log_in` (`ID`, `fullname`, `email`, `country`,`Username`, `Password`,`gender`)";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
header("location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Welcome. You will also want to investigate and protect your inputs from SQL Injection. Check out MySQLi or PDO and start using prepared statements. If this code is in the wild, it would be vulnerable.

Comment: @inuxvd: thanks for wanting to add improvements to questions. However, you've added a spelling error, and are reformatting code, which can sometimes hide the cause of a problem. Unless an OP's code is _really_ unreadable, I advise leaving the code portion alone.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the closing `}` for the if block.

```
if(isset($_POST ['signup'])){
    ...
    ...
} // <-- missing
```

Once that is fixed, you'll find that it doesn't insert your data, because you're not passing any values to the INSERT query. Switch to PDO or MySQLi and use a prepared statement to insert the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a closing bracket for `if` condition.

```
 if(isset($_POST ['signup']))
{
        $fullname = $_POST['fname'];
        $username = $_POST['uname'];
        $email = $_POST['em'];
        $country= $_POST['con'];
        $password = $_POST['pw'];
        $gender= $_POST['gender'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `bookstore`.`log_in` (`ID`, `fullname`, `email`, `country`,`Username`, `Password`,`gender`)";

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    header("location:index.php");
} // closing if condition here
```

**WARNING :**

> mysql is deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO. Your code is vulnerable to SQL
>   Injection.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('page_edit.php');
    if(isset($_POST ['signup'])){
        $fullname = $_POST['fname'];
        $username = $_POST['uname'];
        $email = $_POST['em'];
        $country= $_POST['con'];
        $password = $_POST['pw'];
        $gender= $_POST['gender'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `bookstore`.`log_in` fields (`ID`, `fullname`, `email`, `country`,`Username`, `Password`,`gender`) values ({Put all variables here})";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
header("location:index.php");
}
    ?>
```